# Latex Problem with spacing in table of contents with more than 9 chapters

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

The spacing between the : and title of the chapter disappears when the chapter number exceeds 9.  Here is my code (the input files are empty except for the chapter title, and end with \endinput and output.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?  If I change any parameters, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{PART~}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{6em}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}




\renewcommand{\partname}{PART}

\newcommand{\originalappendix}{}
\let\originalappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \originalappendix
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftpartpresnum}{}%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix~}%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}%
  }%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{APPENDICES}%
  \part*{APPENDICES}%
}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter


\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{}
\input{Ch1}
\input{Ch2}
\input{Ch3}
\input{Ch4}
\input{Ch5}
\input{Ch6}
\input{Ch7}
\input{Ch8}
\input{Ch9}
\input{Ch10}
\input{Ch11}
\input{Ch12}
\input{Ch13}
\input{Ch14}
\input{Ch15}
\input{Ch16}
\input{Ch17}
\input{Ch18}
\input{Ch19}
\input{Ch20}

\end{document}

Contents
PART I
1
Chapter 1: Chapter 1
3
Chapter 2: Chapter 2
5
Chapter 3: Chapter 3
7
Chapter 4: Chapter 5
9
Chapter 5: Chapter 5
11
Chapter 6: Chapter 6
13
Chapter 7: Chapter 7
15
Chapter 8: Chapter 8
17
Chapter 9: Chapter 9
19
Chapter 10:Chapter 10
21
Chapter 11:Chapter 11
23
Chapter 12:Chapter 12
25
Chapter 13:Chapter 13
27
Chapter 14:Chapter 14
29
Chapter 15:Chapter 15
31
Chapter 16:Chapter 16
33
```

Comment: As you are already using the `tocloft` package, I suggest you read it as it already explains how to solve this. Look up `\cftXnumwidth` in the manual and also what the `X` part is.

Comment: Try \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}` not `\renewcommand{\cftchap...}...`